# Looking for a formula to calc row indexing

Tags: matrices

Column A & B are knowns, I want to calculate column D out of them.
What is the appropriate formula for that (Column C)?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not quite clear!?! At least not clear for me...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I dont think it can be more clear than that. I don't even know what to change... `A ? B = D` how do I replace `?`

Comment: For example $C2 = A2 * B2$, but also it can be $C2 = A2 / B2$, or $C2 =B2 / A2$, or $C2 = B2 * A2$, that is why I wrote not quite clear... So, try to explain in more details your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you should use is
$$
\text{result} = 5\cdot (\text{page}-1) + \text{row}
$$
In the language of spreadsheets, it's something like
$$
\text{5(B2-1)+A2}
$$

Comment: Perfect. Will accept that soon! thanks!

Comment: Yup, I marked this answer as useful, but I have Q for @SexyMF: why you need column $C$, a formula given by Matti P. is usually possible to use for column $D$...